# Variable not being correctly evaluated when EnableDelayedExpansion is set

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a variable that apparently is not being correctly evaluated in a condition.

The scenario is the following: I've made a batch file that is set with `SetLocal EnableExtensions`, then it has a main routine that is set with `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion`. The main routine calls a subroutine from within a nested `if` statement passing two parameters, and it gets a variable as a result. The subroutine being called is set with `SetLocal EnableExtensions`.

Problem is that when evaluating the variable that returns the subroutine, apparently the variable is not being correctly evaluated: **a variable that one line before is echoed and confirmed to be equal to zero makes an `if !variable! EQU 0` statement inexplicably return `FALSE`**.

More explanations and details after the code below.

### Sample code (Proof of Concept)

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions 
rem Initialize variables
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set ErrorStatus=0
set PreConditionOne=1
set PreConditionTwo=1
set ValueOne=50
set ValueTwo=50

rem - Main Routine
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion 
rem Setting initial values for flag variables, value can be: 0=NO, 1=YES, 2=Not Checked.
set PreCheckFail=2
set ParamsNotEqual=2
rem Prechecks: Preconditions must be met in order to check variables.
echo Checking PreConditions. 
if %PreConditionOne%==1 (
    echo OK: First PreCondition is met.
    echo Checking Second PreCondition.
    if %PreConditionTwo%==1 (
        echo OK: Second PreCondition is met.
        echo Calling subroutine to check if values match.
        call :Subroutine %ValueOne% %ValueTwo%
    echo Back from subroutine.
        echo InLoop: ErrorLevel: %ErrorLevel%, ErrorStatus: %ErrorStatus%, ParamsNotEqual: %ParamsNotEqual%
        echo InLoopDelayed: ErrorLevel: !ErrorLevel!, ErrorStatus: !ErrorStatus!, ParamsNotEqual: !ParamsNotEqual!
    rem This condition fails to correctly check ParamsNotEqual, it works fine with ErrorLevel.
        if !ParamsNotEqual! EQU 0 (
            echo OK Parameteres verified successfully.
            set PreCheckFail=0
        ) else (
            echo ERROR Parameter verification failed.
            set PreCheckFail=1
        )
    ) else (
        echo ERROR: Second PreCondition is not met.
        set PreCheckFail=1
    )
) else (
    echo ERROR: First PreCondition is not met.
    set PreCheckFail=1
)
echo OutLoop: ErrorLevel: %ErrorLevel%, ErrorStatus: %ErrorStatus%, ParamsNotEqual: %ParamsNotEqual%
echo PreCheckFail: %PreCheckFail%
if %PreCheckFail% EQU 0 (echo "PreCheckFail IS ZERO") else (echo "PreCheckFail NOT ZERO")
endlocal

goto :Finish

:Subroutine
rem Subroutine
rem -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SetLocal EnableExtensions
set ParamOne=%1
set ParamTwo=%2
echo This is the subroutine.
echo The first parameter passed is: %ParamOne%
echo The second parameter passed is: %ParamTwo%
if "%ParamOne%"=="%ParamTwo%" (
    echo OK^! Both variables are equal.
    set ParamsNotEqual=0
    set ErrorStatus=0
) else (
    echo ERROR^! Both variables are different.
    set ParamsNotEqual=1
    set ErrorStatus=1
)
echo EndSub: ErrorLevel: %ErrorLevel%, ErrorStatus: %ErrorStatus%, ParamsNotEqual: %ParamsNotEqual%
endlocal & set ParamsNotEqual=%ParamsNotEqual% & exit /b %ErrorStatus%

:Finish
endlocal
```

If you run this script, you will see that the subroutine correctly returns the `ParamsNotEqual` variable as `0`, then the `echo` lines correctly show the values for both the normally parsed variables and the delayed ones:

```
InLoop: ErrorLevel: 0, ErrorStatus: 0, ParamsNotEqual: 2
InLoopDelayed: ErrorLevel: 0, ErrorStatus: 0, ParamsNotEqual: 0
```

But when the condition `if !ParamsNotEqual! EQU 0` is evaluated, it just fails. Setting `@echo on` does not clarify anything, as the delayed variables are expanded on execution time so I cannot see what is really being evaluated there.

### Test I've done so far

**Things that have no effect so it keeps failing:**

1. Set `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` for the whole script
2. Set `SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` for the subroutine too.
3. Not setting previously the `ParamsNotEqual`variable.
4. Evaluating the condition surrounding it with quotes, or brackets, or using `==` instead of `EQU`.
5. Evaluating `if !ParamsNotEqual! EQU 2` (which is the initial value of the variable) also returns `FALSE`

**Possible workarounds:**

1. Using `!ErrorLevel!` instead of `!ParamsNotEqual!` works fine. This looks logic, as ErrorLevel is a system variable, not a user-defined one.
2. Not setting `SetLocal` for the subroutine, hence having the subroutine variables not isolated from the rest of the script, makes the main routine *automagically* work fine as it is. This has no sense to me but makes me think that this error may be due to some kind of restriction either when calling a subroutine from within a nested `if` when `EnableDelayedExpansion` is set, or with using nested `SetLocal` statements.

I would like to keep using the value of `ParamsNotEqual` instead of `ErrorLevel`, and also, I would like to keep the variables within the subroutine isolated with `SetLocal`.

So, my question: **Is this strange behaviour due to something am I doing wrong or is this a restriction in the way the command processor handles variables when `EnableDelayedExpansion` is set?**

Any hint will be greatly appreciated. If you need any further tests or clarification on the above don't hesitate on asking. A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is correct as `ParamsNotEqual` isn't equal to `0`, as you set it to `0<space>`.

This line contains the problem.

```
endlocal & set ParamsNotEqual=%ParamsNotEqual% & exit /b %ErrorStatus%
```

You should always use the extended syntax of `SET` with surrounding quotes

```
endlocal & set "ParamsNotEqual=%ParamsNotEqual%" & ...
```

Comment: Man, I'm banging my head against the table right now: that space was exactly the problem. Thanks a lot! :-)